# Unable to symbolicate Xamarin Android stacktrace

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

I execute *mono-symbolicate mSYM_path crash.txt > result.txt* but the output is always empty.

The project is correctly configured:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugType>PdbOnly</DebugType>
  <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
  <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
```

If I execute mono-symbolicate -h it does not return anything

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to symbolicate a Xamarin Android crash log using the mono-symbolicate OSX version, something is wrong in the windows version of mono-symbolicate. The project was correctly configured and the syntax of the execution was fine too.

The mono-symbolicate available at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android

seems to be obsolete, you should use the executable located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android